# How to use design patterns for a lot of interdependent state?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, class-design

We have an application which runs every 5-10 minutes, and the job of the application is to use latest data to update in-memory state for objects of class `Foo`.
The class state can be represented as:

```
Class Foo {
 int foo1;
 double foo2;
 bar foo3;
 double foo4;
 ...
 ...
 int fooN;
}
```

So for the `n'th` run of this application which gets latest data `bazObj(n)` of class `Baz`, `Foo(n) = f(Foo(n-1), Baz(n))`
The tricky thing here is that there are lot of interdpendencies in the computation. For example, the computation of `foo3` depends on `foo1` being already updated, `foo4` computation depends on `foo2` and `foo3` being already updated and so on.

Our current design is a simple sequential flow which implicitly has all these dependencies that aren't captured or enforced anywhere, making the code hard to maintain.

What would be good ways to structure the computation of `Foo(n)` to make the code flow intuitive and easy to understand/maintain (using C++)? Any pointers to relevant design patterns would also be helpful.

Comment: Kind of observers maybe? Your question is pretty broad without giving some more concise sample.

Comment: What kind of observers are you thinking about? The state of the observers is also dependent on each other which is the tricky part.
Also, this is a cycle-based application, so knowing that the state of object Foo needs to be updated isn't the hard part here.

Comment: This isn't entirely clear.  Is `foo1 = ...; foo2 = ...; foo3 = ... + foo1;` etc. not maintainable?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Yup that's exactly the issue. There are like 50 different foo_i's and maintaining the dependency between them is a nightmare.

Comment: Ok, if the issue is keeping the update statements in the correct order in your code, you might consider building a dependency tree, which would allow you to declare your updates in an arbitrary order.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Can you elaborate on the "dependency tree" aspect a bit or point to an example? It's not clear to me how such a dependency tree can be built using C++ features.

Comment: Write out all the dependency in a graph, topological-sort it, and you get the order you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal seems to be to compute each object after the objects it depends on have been computed.  It sounds like you have been doing this by hand in your code and finding it to be bug prone.

Here is a simple approach.  It can be greatly improved by sorting based on dependencies, but it will get the job done.

```
create a list of every object with a list of objects that it depends on
while (some objects are not computed)
    for (each uncomputed object)
        if (object's dependencies are met)
            compute object
            Mark as computed
```

Doing this will make you code simpler because you can simply add/modify your objects and their immediate dependencies without worrying about where to add them in the list.  The above algorithm will make sure they are computed in the proper order.

This is not a particularly fast method--it's brute force, but easy.  It can be significantly improved.

You can record the order that you computed the objects and reuse it in a subsequent pass (assuming nothing has changed).